# Publish-Module "Get-PackageSource Unable to find repository 'ArtifactoryDev'" error. Though ArtifactoryDev exists

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershellget

Unable to publish an update to an existing Powershell module to our Artifact Store.

In my script I register my repositories and Package Sources:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name ArtifactoryDev -SourceLocation $NuGetDevUrl -PublishLocation $NuGetDevUrl -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $Cred
    Register-PackageSource -Name ArtifactoryDev -ProviderName NuGet -Location $NuGetDevUrl -Trusted -Credential $Cred
```

I then, near the end of my script try to publish the module to update our existing one in Artifactory:

```
    Publish-Module -Path $Module.Path -Repository $RepositoryName -NuGetApiKey "$($ArtifactoryUser):$($ArtifactoryToken)" -Credential $Cred -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose -Debug
```

I am getting the following error

```
2019-06-27T12:12:24.2452350Z ##[error]PackageManagement\Get-PackageSource : Unable to find repository 'ArtifactoryDev'. Use Get-PSRepository to see all 
available repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.1.5\PSModule.psm1:9360 char:35
+ ... ckageSources = PackageManagement\Get-PackageSource @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...etPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource] 
   , Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SourceNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageSource
```

To check the repository does exist I thought to call 
Get-PackageSource -Name ArtifatoryDev

and I can see it in the results:

```
Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
ArtifactoryDev                   PowerShellGet    True        http://myremoterepo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issues with the publish function. Have you tried to unregister and reregister the repo just before the publish? I have found that does the trick. For some reason, the publish module does an anon call to the repo to check versions (I think) before publishing and if the repo is secure (or doesn't have anon auth allowed) you can get errors. By unregistering and reregistering the repo just before the publish, I've found that is somehow gets around the anon call... not sure exactly why.